# Trait bounds did not work out for enums as generic parameter

Tags: rust

For a larger Programm, I've tried to introduce a new trait to pass some different enums through a function.

We got this situation:

```
enum One { One, Two}
enum Two {Three, Four}
```

I used a trait like this:

```
pub trait NewTrait {}
```

Then:

```
impl NewTrait for One {}
impl NewTrait for Two {}
```

then we have a function:

```
fn foo<T: NewTrait> (test: T) {
match test{
    One::One => println!("One"),
    One::Two => println!("Two"),
    Two::Three => println!("Three"),
    Two::Four => println!("Four"),
    }
}
```

We use:

```
fn main() {
    foo(One::One);
    foo(Two::Three);
}
```

Then I got this errormessage:

```
Compiling Examplecode v0.1.0 (/Users/maximilianwittich/projects/Examplecode)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
9  | enum One { One, Two}
   |            --- unit variant defined here
...
16 | fn foo<T: NewTrait>(test: T) {
   |        - this type parameter
17 |     match test{
   |           ---- this expression has type `T`
18 |         One::One => println!("One!"),
   |         ^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found enum `One`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found enum `One`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
9  | enum One { One, Two}
   |                 --- unit variant defined here
...
16 | fn foo<T: NewTrait>(test: T) {
   |        - this type parameter
17 |     match test{
   |           ---- this expression has type `T`
18 |         One::One => println!("One!"),
19 |         One::Two => println!("Two!"),
   |         ^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found enum `One`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found enum `One`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:9
   |
10 | enum Two {Three, Four}
   |           ----- unit variant defined here
...
16 | fn foo<T: NewTrait>(test: T) {
   |        - this type parameter
17 |     match test{
   |           ---- this expression has type `T`
...
20 |         Two::Three => println!("Three!"),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found enum `Two`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found enum `Two`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:21:9
   |
10 | enum Two {Three, Four}
   |                  ---- unit variant defined here
...
16 | fn foo<T: NewTrait>(test: T) {
   |        - this type parameter
17 |     match test{
   |           ---- this expression has type `T`
...
21 |         Two::Four => println!("Four!")
   |         ^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found enum `Two`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found enum `Two`

error: aborting due to 4 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `Examplecode`
```

[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoNiZ.png)

Can anybody explain to me what's going on? Maybe with a bit brighter explanation, since I honestly try to learn to code in Rust.

Comment: The idea of StackOverflow is not only to answer questions for the person asking, but also for people having similar questions in the future. For that reason, you should include the error message in you question as text, not as a screenshot. Also note that the code in your question does not match the code in the error messages.

Comment: All the compiler knows about the generic type `T` in `foo()` is that it implements the trait `NewTrait`, so the only operations you can perform on values of type `T` are those defined in that trait – in other words, none at all, since the trait is empty. In particular, the compiler does not know how to compare values of type `T` to values of type `One` or `Two`.

Comment: You cannot `match` on a trait.

Comment: First of all, you are right and I was a bit lazy.

I do not understand in particular what type of action I try to perform here? In other words, what should the trait provide to use the match switch?

Comment: A trait is the wrong type of abstraction if you want to match. Perhaps you wanted `enum New { One(One), Two(Two) }` so you can `match test { New::One(One::One) => {}, New::Two(Two::Three) => {}, ... }`? You would use a trait if you wanted multiple types to have similar *functionality*, provide some kind of numeric value perhaps? (i.e. `trait NewTrait { fn value(&self) -> i32 }`). In your question its not clear what you actually want to do with `test` so its hard to say how you should architect it.

Comment: Well, hard to describe now. I write a program for Magic the Gathering (idk if some of you know). We have cards there that have categories (Creatures, Instant, Land, ...). Theses cards serve different proposes like removal, card draw,.... . The first enum is Cardtype, containing basic card types like Creatures. The second enum is Subcategory like removal. I try to figure out some hypergeometric for every cardtype and subcategorie. Therefore I need to pass both enum's into the function, match them in order to define the successfull draw. It works well using only one of the enums.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand in particular what type of action I try to perform here? In other words, what should the trait provide to use the match switch?

Instead of attempting to match across all possibilities (which is impossible, as any number of types could implement the trait), your trait should provide the *behavior* you need in `foo`. For example:

```
// enum One and Two defined as in the question

pub trait NewTrait {
    fn display(&self);
}

impl NewTrait for One {
    fn display(&self) {
        match self {
            One::One => println!("One"),
            One::Two => println!("Two"),
        }
    }
}

impl NewTrait for Two {
    fn display(&self) {
        match self {
            Two::Three => println!("Three"),
            Two::Four => println!("Four"),
        }
    }
}

fn foo<T: NewTrait>(test: T) {
    test.display();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=49dae63a9c26829bd868dc85409430a3)

If you really insisted on matching all options, the trait could provide that as well, e.g. using a custom enum that squashes the existing enums:

```
// enum One and Two defined as in the question

enum Match {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
}

trait NewTrait {
    fn as_match(&self) -> Match;
}

impl NewTrait for One {
    fn as_match(&self) -> Match {
        match self {
            One::One => Match::One,
            One::Two => Match::Two,
        }
    }
}

impl NewTrait for Two {
    fn as_match(&self) -> Match {
        match self {
            Two::Three => Match::Three,
            Two::Four => Match::Four,
        }
    }
}

fn foo<T: NewTrait>(test: T) {
    match test.as_match() {
        Match::One => println!("One"),
        Match::Two => println!("Two"),
        Match::Three => println!("Three"),
        Match::Four => println!("Four"),
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=710debf5853e05483e07ee6672433add)

It's hard to tell whether this makes any sense because we don't know the actual problem you're trying to solve. But hopefully it gives you an idea of what you can accomplish with traits and generics.

See also the chapter on traits in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html).